# Trying to show bullet text in html

Tags: html, css, asp.net, view, pre

I have some paragraphs in a database that actually are a list of elements, but were copy and paste all the text as one paragraph from a Word document.

[image]

Now I need to show the text with the same style, if I just show the text in the html it looks like a paragraph with the bullets included in the text. I have been looking for html tags that respect the new lines in the text and I found `<pre>` I have been working with some option for made the result with the same style that the rest of the view, but I am stock trying to change the indentation. So far what I have is this:

[image]

```
pre {
   display: block;
   padding: 9.5px;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   line-height: 1.42857143;
   color: #333;
   border-radius: 4px;
   overflow: initial!important;
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```

I need the text align with the text not with the bullets like I have now. I am looking for something that allow me change that or maybe another way to show the text.

Comment: Please could you show your rendered source html too

Comment: Why not use the html `ul` and `li` tags?

Answer (score 0):

change white-space: pre-line to white-space: pre.
it will work.